# Gdm3 doesn't start after installing ATI d

Tags: ati, fglrx, debian

I have just installed some graphics drivers on my Debian 6. I used `sgfxi` script which generated `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and installed ATI drivers. After installation which was succeeded I couldn't start Gnome again. I saw only blinking cursor on the plain screen. When I rebooted system it looked the same. I used to use Debian about two years ago but I had never such problems with X-server.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the compatibility problems between your display manager gdm3 and your Graphics driver. Here is a tutorial which explains how to install ATI graphics card drivers without causing an Issue with your display manager : [How to Install ATI drivers in debian ?](http://www.securethelock.com/2014/01/15/how-to-install-amdati-drivers-in-debian/)

If you want to boot back in to your machine again, you have to un-install the existing drivers by going to the recovery mode and Un-installing the drivers. [[Fix]Gdm3 doesn’t start after installing ATI/AMD drivers in Debian !](http://www.securethelock.com/2014/01/15/fix-gdm3-doesnt-start-installing-atiamd-drivers-debian/)